# Controlling an $.ajax function within a js "for" loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my issue. I have a js function that performs an $.ajax call to fetch some data from a server. When it gets that data back, I need to pass control back to the browser in order to show an update to a div. 
The js function is itself within a for loop, and I need to ensure that the for loop does not advance until the js function has updated the div and allowed the Browser to display that update, at which point the for loop advances and the js function (with its ajax call) is called again, continuing until the for loop test causes the loop to end.

I've tried many different approaches - callbacks, promises etc, but to date I can't seem to get a handle on ensuring that the loop doesn't advance until the js function gets its server data, updates the div, causes the browser to display that update and fully completes.

Here's a simple stripped-down version of the function:

```
function myFunction (email) {
    var request = $.ajax( {
       url: 'getit.php',
       cache: false,
       async: false,
       method: "post",
       timeout: 1000,
       data: "requesttype=getemailname&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)
    });
    request.done(function(response) {
         $("#myDiv").html(response);
    });
}
```

and here's part of the js that calls it:

```
.....

var emailscount = emails.length;
for(var i=0;i<emailscount;i++) {
    myFunction (emails[i]);
}

.....
```

So, my issues are:

1) **myFunction** must allow the browser to display the updated div html - I'm not sure how to achieve that?

2) the for loop ***should only proceed*** when **myFunction** has received the data back from the server, updated the div html, **AND** allowed the browser to display that div.

At the moment, I have set the $.ajax call async flag set to "false" to stop execution until the data comes back, but how do I ensure the browser displays the new div content, and that the for loop does not proceed to call **myFunction** again until the previous **myFunction** call fully completes?

Any help you can give me would be very welcome, as right now I can't get this all to work!

Comment: Read the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ that states `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().`

Comment: Forget limitation #2, that's the source of your problem. Your JS loop *must* complete before the browser can redraw. Using `async=false` is not the solution to anything, it's been deprecate outside of workers because it locks the rendering, and only poorly designed code relies on it. Consider chaining the requests together, using jQuery's deferred objects (which are like promises).

Comment: Quickest way to get what you want is to use jQuery < 1.8 with the async field set to false. Ultimately the best way to get what you want is to learn how to program asynchronously. You will be using javascript in an inefficient manner if you rely on synchronous ajax calls.

Comment: @hofan41 They're already doing that, but it's not updating the view like they want, so they need async code.

Comment: I've made progress on this - thanks! Please see below for a further answer/question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a recursive function, not a `for` loop with synchronous ajax calls

```
(function myFunction(i) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getit.php',
        method: "post",
        timeout: 1000,
        data: {
            requesttype : 'getemailname',
            email : emails[i]
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        $("#myDiv").html(response);
        if (emails[++i]) myFunction(i); // continue when this one is done
    });
})(0);
```

Comment: Ew, synchronous ajax? D:

Comment: @SterlingArcher What ? This isn't synchronous

Comment: @SterlingArcher - yup, also well known as *"Synchronous Asynchronous Javascript And XML"*

Comment: And vanah white @adeneo ?

Comment: There probably should be parens to make it clearer: *"Sounds like you need a recursive function, not (a for loop and synchronous ajax)"*

Comment: Thanks adeneo - knew it was simpler than the convoluted mess I'd got into :-)  your recursion with .done replaced with .success etc should do it!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's help! I'm making good progress (including taking care of JQuery deprecations!) but have run into a further problem. As I need to hand control back to the browser in order to show the refreshed div as I recurse, I'm calling a setTimeout as follows:

```
var nextBitOfWork = function () {
    return myFunction(email);
};
setTimeout(nextBitOfWork, 0);
```

where myFunction (which recurses) now returns a promise when it's done doing it's $.ajax call.

If I simply call:

```
return myFunction(email);
```

without the setTimeout function construct above, the promise is passed through and all my promises are captured and allow me to get the array output I need and everything works great. But without the setTimeout I don't get the browser refresh. Using it as above I get the div update refresh displaying, but seem to lose the promise and so the script continues and I don't get to fill the array I use to capture values as I recurse.

Any thoughts on how to make sure the setTimeout passes on the promise?

Thanks